# Cancel workflows before archiving repo in GitHub

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, github-api, github-ci

**Aim:** I want to archive repo

**Problem:** from time to time, thera are active actions and they can stuck and endlessly keep running after archivation.

**Found solution:** [Steps GitHub takes to cancel a workflow run.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/canceling-a-workflow#steps-github-takes-to-cancel-a-workflow-run)

**Question:** If I send a workflow cancellation request, will it be canceled within a maximum of 5 minutes in any case?

Comment: According to docs, "_After the 5 minutes cancellation timeout period, the server will force terminate all jobs and steps that don't finish running or fail to complete the cancellation process._", have you observed anything different? You can simply use a long running script to test this.